# Why is an edit link disabled on a question that is not locked, on-hold, or closed?

Tags: support, editing

I was going to remove the "cats" tag on the question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56141/how-do-we-kill-all-the-cats-in-israel  Not terribly important, just some community clean-up work.  I cannot though since the "edit" link is disabled.  I cannot figure out why that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because there is already a pending suggested edit. Until it's approved or rejected, other edits can't be suggested. The edit is doing exactly that btw. :P

See [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) on MSE.

Comment: Very good.  Thank you for clarifying.